# Something to prevent wind sensor from freezing

Tags: pcb-design, ptc

I am trying to prevent the wind sensor from freezing - I know there are heated ones but they are not cheap. These versions have 1-4W heating, so I think it would be enough to have this range of heat dissipation. I have a 5V power source with enough power.

I've come up with three options:

1. PTC heater - the one I like best because it is sort of self regulating BUT it seems there are no elements with a 10-20˚C limit.
2. Simple fixed resistor - this would heat up and use power even in very hot weather and could damage the part being heated. Not battery powered but don't want to waste power either.
3. PCB with microcontroller, heating resistor, mosfet etc ....

I would prefer simple to complex, but it seems there is no other option than the third. Are there any other options? How to prevent ice on the wind sensor properly?

Comment: How about WD-40 ?

Comment: Unfortunately, WD-40 will not prevent the sensor from turning into a snowball...

Comment: @user22108 It seems as though you'd like *just enough* power to be applied to keep things working right. Obviously, weather varies a lot. So any circuit that has a way of providing *just enough* will have to have a way of knowing what that happens to be in any given case. In short, I think a sensor is needed. You can *go analog* by using a standard PI loop controller for the heating element. By the way, I do *not* know what you mean by `it seems there are no elements with a 10-20˚C limit` in the context of a PTC heater. Could you expand on that?

Comment: @user22108 You could just buy the entire thing. Search for `STC-1000 Temperature Controller Digital Thermostat w/ NTC Sensor`. These things are very cheap and come with 12VDC, 24VDC, or 110-220VAC editions at under USD10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a simple solution, consider a **thermostatic switch**.  These are passive devices, typically a bimetallic strip pushing a contact, often in a sealed package.  Some are specifically designed for freeze protection in water pipes, and so have the thermal switching suitable for your application.  A typical one I found opens on temperature rise: open by 7°C, close by 2°C, which may be exactly what you need.  Connect with your heater chosen empirically.

Many shapes and form factors are available: here's a typical pipe-mount one:

[image]

*From [Senasys](https://senasys.com/product/2570l439-34-epoxy-sealed-thermostat/), which advertises its products for [freeze protection](https://senasys.com/preventing-frozen-pipes/).  Very many other industrial manufacturers produce comparable products.*